# Minimum distance larger than a fraction $f$ of the closest nearest-neighbor distances for points placed by a random Poisson process?

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry

Consider a random Poisson process on arbitrarily large volume in $R^d$ enclosed by an $R^{(d-1)}$ dimensional sphere.  The process terminates when a density of points $\rho$ is achieved (letting $N$ equal the number of points, we have $\rho = \frac{N}{V_{d}(R)}$).  Is there a nice closed-form expression for the the minimum distance, $l_{NN}$ in $d$ dimensions that is larger than the closest nearest-neighbor distance for some fraction, $f$, of the points?  In lieu of this, what if we concern ourselves with the median closest nearest-neighbor distance?  I suppose it would be a fair assumption that the closest nearest neighbor distance should decay exponentially as a function of $\rho$.

Comment: I think there are some issues with your problem statement. You cannot sample points with uniform distribution in $\mathbb R^d$. Also, what do you mean by "achieving a density"?

Comment: @JorisBierkens Let me attempt to fix the problems.